# Storing variable within controller on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, action

I know there is a lot of information available for passing variables between one controller action and another, both within the same controller and to other controllers.

But what I am trying to do, which I have been unable to find any documentation on, is temporarily store a variable in one controller action, so that it is available when another controller action(within the same controller) is called shortly after.

I tried using an instance variable but it didn't work.

I don't believe I can use flash because that is only for the very next action.

A class variable wouldn't be suitable because it would lead to conflicts if users were doing things simultaneously.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you tell us exactly what you are trying to do it would help us give you suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to use the session for this in your controller during first pass:

```
session[:save_me] = "for next time"
```

then on the next time in there

```
if( session[:save_me] )
 #do cool stuff here
 session[:save_me] = nil 
end
```

Http is stateless so we use a session to pass information from request to request.